# Using dates, is "between" inclusive of the start and end dates, or is "from" more appropriate?

Tags: word-choice, dates, range-inclusion

Specific case is a period of work that began one date and ended on another date, but only periodically *between* those dates.

For example:

> Services were performed periodically between July 1 and July 16.

I think ***from*** July 1 through July 17 a better choice, but my manager keeps editing it to "between."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the closing date mean exactly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/471277/what-does-the-closing-date-mean-exactly) Tuffy examines the ambiguity, the 'boundary problem' that crops up with dates, numbers (and various words such as 'from ... to'; 'between' ...). // With your example, it hardly matters. 'Services were performed periodically between June 25 and July 26' is equally truthful (and neither is precisionist). But sometimes, the ambiguity is serious.

Comment: The issue here is whether "between" implicitly includes the endpoints of a range or only the elements that fall within the figurative space between them. Idiomatically, many people use "between" inclusively without any fear that it might be read as excluding the endpoints from the range. Nevertheless, some publishers (including the one that I work for) are sticklers about using "from X to [or _through_] Y" instead of "between X and Y" when the author intends to include the endpoints in the range. I wonder, though, how many readers would interpret "between 2019 and 2021" to mean "during 2020."

Comment: If it is important and you are worried the text may not be clear, you are free to add some clarifying text. As "July 1 to July 16, inclusive" for example. If it is important then adding a few seemingly unrequired words is not a problem.